# Need Help in Setting Correct Designer 2013 Logic to Send an Email Reminder

Tags: 2013, designer-workflow, reminder

I have an InfoPath 2010 List form. Below is a screenshot of 2 controls that is involved in my question. For the dropdown the selections are New, Advanced and Closed. As for the Date Picker control, I have it set to display a default value of Created Date + 14 days and can be changed whenever the Admin feels it to be necessary.

[image]

Below is my Designer 2013 logic attached to the same List that the InfoPath form is published to (don’t ask why I’m using 2010 IP on SP2013). To make clear, TestReminder is a Calculated Column on the List with a value =Created+14. Also, I used the Loop condition below in order to satisfy the condition to send daily emails to the Admin if TestReminder=Completion Date, which when initially submitted by a Requestor (not the Admin) is True.

[image]

For this example I’ll use the Completion Date set above as **4/24/2016**. The task/condition is:

- On **4/24/2016** (*Completion Date*), send an email reminder to the Admin
  to either set a **new Completion Date** or **set the Selected
  Request Status to Closed**. If the Completion Date has been reached,
  and the task has not been completed, **send daily email** to
  remind the Admin.
- If the Admin **sets a new Completion Date**, for example from 4/24/2016 to
  5/1/2016, then **Pause until the new Completion Date** and send an email
  reminder to either **set a new Completion Date** or **set the Selected
  Request Status to Closed**. If the Completion Date has been reached and
  the task has not been completed, **send daily email** to remind
  the Admin.
- If the Admin sets the **Request Status to Closed**, send an email to the
  Admin and **End the Workflow**.

The main problem I'm having, and I know it, is that when the Admin sets the Request Status to Closed, the column TestReminder is still equal to Completion Date which results in the process looping back to the beginning.

Can someone assist with the correct logic in executing the conditions I mentioned? Any help is appreciated.